# Curl Redirecting to my own website instead of to members only link on the target website

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to obtain some information from a webpage that requires login. I am using PHP/cURL to post username and password to the login page on the target website. The website uses relative links to redirect authenticated users to a members only area.

I am getting 200 OK and I can see that I am being successfully authenticated. My issue is that I don't know how to make it go to the actual member area in the target website (targetwebsite.com/memberarea) as opposed to mywebsite.com/memberarea.  Is there a way to specify the base domain of the target website in cURL? Could you also tell me if I am doing something not recommended in the following code.

Here is what I am doing...

```
<?php
// INIT CURL
$ch = curl_init();

// SET URL FOR THE POST FORM LOGIN
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://targetwebsite.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// SET POST PARAMETERS : FORM VALUES FOR EACH FIELD
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=someuser&password=mypassword');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
$header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 


// IMITATE CLASSIC BROWSER'S BEHAVIOUR : HANDLE COOKIES
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

# Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
# not to print out the results of its query.
# Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
# from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);

// EXECUTE 1st REQUEST (FORM LOGIN)
$store = curl_exec ($ch);


// SET FILE TO DOWNLOAD
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://targetwebsite.com?memberarea+welcome+UserFirstName');


// EXECUTE 2nd REQUEST (FILE DOWNLOAD)
$content = curl_exec ($ch);

//echo $store;

// CLOSE CURL
curl_close ($ch); 


?>
```

Comment: Are you receiving a Location: redirect?
If so, use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you receiving a Location: redirect? If so, use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`

Also, Christian Sciberras recommends setting MAXREDIRECTS to at least 3. [Proof](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2342478#2342478)

Comment: This was one of the issue. Other than that, I also had to forge the Referer in the HTTP header as it was being checked for security reasons.